# MySQL - convert timed event rows to ranges of states

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

Let's say a house gets painted every so often, and I track the changes (the 'paint' event) in a simple table:

```
 _______________________
/ PaintDate | NewColor  \
|-----------|-----------|
| 1/2/2012  |  Red      |
| 3/5/2013  |  Blue     |
| 9/9/2013  |  Green    |
\___________|___________/
```

Is there a SELECT statement that can give me a table of **the date ranges a house was at a specific color**?

Desired output:

```
 _______________________________
/  From    |   To     |  Color  \
|----------|----------|---------|
| 1/2/2012 | 3/5/2013 |   Red   |
| 3/5/2013 | 9/9/2013 |   Blue  |
| 9/9/2013 | NULL     |   Green | -- Not repainted yet, the date in the 'To' column should be NULL
\__________|__________|_________/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use this query

```
SELECT 
  p.PaintDate AS `From`,
  l.PaintDate AS `TO`,
  p.NewColor AS `Color` 
FROM
  paint AS p 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM paint LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615) AS l   
    ON l.PaintDate = (SELECT PaintDate FROM paint WHERE PaintDate > p.PaintDate ORDER BY PaintDate ASC LIMIT 1)
```

OUTPUT

```
From       |    TO          | Color
-------------------------------
2012-02-01 |    2012-05-03  | Red
2012-05-03 |    2013-09-09  | Blue
2013-09-09 |    (NULL)      | Green
```

### Demo

The above query can be improved like this

```
SELECT 
  p.PaintDate AS `From`,
  l.PaintDate AS `TO`,
  p.NewColor AS `Color` 
FROM
  paint AS p 
  LEFT JOIN paint AS l ON l.PaintDate = (SELECT PaintDate FROM paint WHERE PaintDate > p.PaintDate ORDER BY PaintDate ASC  LIMIT 1)
```

### Demo

Comment: 1. Why the `LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615`?

Comment: So when joining avoid the first record

Comment: 2. (sorry, thought `enter` gives me a newline) And how do I know for sure the dates are ordered? `PaintDate > p.PaintDate` can return any date later than `p.PaintDate`, can't it?

Comment: you are missing limit and you can order by date asc

Comment: i have added order by in my answer you can check

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  aa.PaintDate `FROM`, bb.PaintDate `TO`,
        aa.NewColor
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  @row:=@row+1 as RankNo,
                    a.PaintDate,
                    a.NewColor
            FROM    tableName a, (SELECT @row:=0) b
            ORDER   BY a.PaintDate
        ) aa
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  @row2:=@row2+1 as RankNo,
                    a.PaintDate
            FROM    tableName a, (SELECT @row2:=0) b
            ORDER   BY a.PaintDate
        ) bb ON aa.RankNo+1 = bb.RankNo
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97e8f/3)